# POSTMAN SFMC: Auth URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, oauth2

I am trying to use Post Man for SOAP Calls. I am having issues finding where the Auth URL is for salesforce marketing cloud/ exacttarget. Please refer to the pic below:

[image]

I will appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell from the documentation there is no Auth URL. At least none mentioned in the documentation. You simply use your Client Id and Secret to request a token

Maybe this collection of calls will help you get started in getting a token via rest them making your SOAP call from postman with payload:

> You must call the Auth/RequestToken REST API to get a 60 minute accessToken before making subsequent token based SOAP API calls.

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/postman

Answer (score -2):

I would like to suggest to get the SOAP Request and Response and call it using APEX code. Before that use the SOAPUI free version to test the request and response with the endpoint URL. The SOAPUI Link - https://www.soapui.org/

POSTMAN is very much helpful for the RESTFull services.

Comment: And how does this answer the question about the Auth URL using the REST API?

Comment: @Eric, I am extremely surprised to see your basic understanding is entirely wrong. I go through the document you referred in your earlier post, and nowhere I find the Webservice call using SOAP. It only talks about the REST API and the standard configurations of the creation of custom APP with Client_ID and Client_Secret and so on and so forth. 

So SOAP ca not be used in any format here. I can refer to the excellent document written by Pat Patterson into hs article 
"Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 on Force.com"

Comment: @Eric, The article can be found at the following URL https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Comment: I can give you each and every step to authenticate and authorize and call the REST service using POSTMAN.

Comment: since the OP is asking for oAuth parameters that is a REST call so by all means....tell them what the AuthURL is for ExactTarget.....